# How to use Collections.sort() on two different fields?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have a `Member` class like this :

```
public class Member {
    private int value1;
    private boolean value2;
}
```

And an `ArrayList<Member>` containing this data :

**value1 - value2**

- 1 - false
- 2 - false
- 3 - true
- 4 - false
- 5 - true

Now I want this data sorted this way :

- The members with `value2` as true must be returned first, then the other ones after
- In each sublist, members will be returned from the highest to the lowest `value1`

So in the end, the list should contain data in this order : 5, 3, 4, 2, 1.

I know that I can use `Collections.sort()` to sort data by value1 :

```
Collections.sort(memberList, new Comparator<Member>(){
    public int compare(Member m1, Member m2){
        return m1.getValue1() - m2.getValue1();
    }
});
```

But is there a way to sort data by both criterias in the same `compare` method?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: code inside compare is all yours. You can compare m1.getVaue2() vs m2.getValue2()...

Comment: It´s not like you can just write a single line in the method compare...

Comment: Geez.... @Rob learn to [search](http://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework) before you ask

Answer (score 2):

You can compare by `value2` first, and then in the case of a tie compare by `value1`:

```
Collections.sort(memberList, new Comparator<Member>(){
    public int compare(Member m1, Member m2){
        int comp = Boolean.compare(m1.getValue2(), m2.getValue2());

        if (comp == 0) {
            // case where 'value2' is the same for both inputs
            // in this case use 'value1' to compare
            comp = m1.getValue1() - m2.getValue1();
        }
        return comp;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Collections.sort(memberList, new Comparator<Member>(){
    public int compare(Member m1, Member m2){
        int res = Boolean.compare(m2.getValue2(), m1.getValue2());
        if(res == 0) res = Integer.compare(m2.getValue1(), m1.getValue1());
        return res;
    }
});
```

This can be done much more simply in Java-8:

```
Collections.sort(memberList, 
       Comparator.comparing(Member::getValue2).thenComparing(Member::getValue1).reversed());
```